# Unable to deploy docker container with Goland - DockerClientException - .eslintrc (No such file or directory)

Tags: docker, go, goland

I am building a go app inside a docker container

When I try to run a docker container inside Golang with this command preview

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.local -t myGoApp:exp . && docker run -v /volume:/go --name myGoApp --env-file ./test.env --network=myGoApp_network myGoApp:exp
```

I get:

```
Building image...
Failed to deploy 'myGoApp Dockerfile: Dockerfile.local': com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Error occurred while preparing Docker context folder.<br/>caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/julien/go/src/gitlab.com/xxx/myGoApp/vendor/github.com/influxdata/platform/chronograf/.eslintrc (No such file or directory)
```

When I run the same command on a terminal, it works

When I run the equivalent inside a docker compose via Goland, it also works.

I also checked, and the `.eslintrc` in question exists.

Why is it happening ? Googling, I could find that it has to do with docker-java, but I could not really find a way to solution.

Here is docker version info:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:35:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:02:44 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Any idea what's wrong ? I need to launch it that way because I want to implement debugging inside a container like explained [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/04/30/debugging-containerized-go-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the volume for broken hard links or symlinks to things that don't exist on your host file system. It won't build the image if the destination of the links do not resolve to a file. This was my issue when I was dealing with it.